# May I build more than two layers of endpoint in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I know when flask builds large application, it has registered multiple blueprints.

The flask blueprint starts to initial a blueprint object, it has declared name of first layer of endpoint in the same time.

For example:

```
users_bp = Blueprint('users', __name__)
```

According to the expression, the name of first layer of endpoint of `users_bp` is `users`.

The blueprint object continues to register its view function, it has declared name of second layer of endpoint in the same time.

```
@users_bp.route('/login')
    def login():
        # do something
```

According to the expression, the name of second layer of endpoint of `users_bp` is `login`, it's from view name.

If I want to use `endpoint` to get corresponding url, I should be to do : `url_for('users.login')`.

So it's workflow of building large application from flask tutorial. Is it right?

---

Let's get back on point. Is it possible to build three layers of endpoint as `url_for('api. users.login')`?

How do I package the blueprint or flask app to complete my wanted structure? Is it available?

Answer (score 0):

You can set an endpoint within your route decorator, for example:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', endpoint="this.is.the.home.endpoint")
def index():
    _html="<a href='{{url_for('this.is.another.endpoint')}}'>Go to another endpoint</a>"
    return render_template_string(_html)


@app.route('/another', endpoint="this.is.another.endpoint")
def another():
    _html="<a href='{{url_for('this.is.the.home.endpoint')}}'>Go to the home page</a>"
    return render_template_string(_html)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```